# In spark 2.x , other than using DF.write.mode().jdbc()....., how to write Dataframe data into mysql

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, jdbc

I want to keep updating a mysql table with some aggregated results I get from a hive table through a spark job running every few hours. I have the aggregated result in the form a dataframe.

I have tried DF.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc()..., but I guess the meaning of Append is not the same as Upsert. It fails, if the same unique key combination in row that it is trying to insert, already exists in table.

I guess the other way would be to repartition(by a column) the dataframe and for each partition write my own upsert statements? Is this how everyone is inserting any data which is constantly updating from a aggregated dataframe to mysql?

Comment: I don't think that Spark and MySQL is the best tools to use in this case. However, you can also use directly the MySQL JDBC driver, as shown here: https://medium.com/@thomaspt748/how-to-upsert-data-into-relational-database-using-spark-7d2d92e05bb9